# file_get_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I'm getting a rather weird error

```
file_get_contents('/var/www/site/config/../runtime/cookies/1a8dd816aafc1118dc5cbf7fd0263f20/cookie.txt'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

So I changed the code to:

```
if (file_exists($cookie_file)) {
    echo file_get_contents($cookie_file);
} else {
    echo "$cookie_file does not exist\n";
}
```

And it outputs:

```
/var/www/site/config/../runtime/cookies/1a8dd816aafc1118dc5cbf7fd0263f20/cookie.txt does not exist
```

In the command line if I do

```
cat /var/www/site/config/../runtime/cookies/1a8dd816aafc1118dc5cbf7fd0263f20/cookie.txt
```

It cats the file just fine

Permissions are fine too:

```
ls -lrt /var/www/site/config/../runtime/cookies/1a8dd816aafc1118dc5cbf7fd0263f20/cookie.txt
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 391 Feb 11 16:27 /var/www/site/config/../runtime/cookies/1a8dd816aafc1118dc5cbf7fd0263f20/cookie.txt
```

So yeah, I'm rather confused to why it won't read the file that clearly exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: File may not have permission to be read/written.

Comment: Its the `..` thats giving you trouble.

Comment: /var/www/site/config/../ ? What is the /../ for?

Comment: I just did a test where I write the file to `/tmp/cookies/`, so basically no `..` in the path and the same thing happens. The file is created, but I still can't read from it. Permissions are `-rw-rw-r--`

Comment: sorry, the permission is `rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Don't you have to wrap your file between quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `realpath` to expand relative path to absolute path. `..` between `config` and `runtime` in path means its relative, while `file_get_contents` require absolute.